# Dynamically proxy a file download in AWS API Gateway

Tags: nginx, proxy, aws-api-gateway

**My use case**

I have an external service that provides dynamically create PDF files for download. That services puts the PDF file on a file server and gives back the URL that will be valid for 15 minutes. My users need to download these PDF files. I don't want to expose the URL to the users so I want to proxy pass this on my API Gateway.

**Current working implementation**

The current implementation is using NGINX and proxy pass to download the file. I want to remove my NGINX and use API Gateway for all my requests.
NGINX config:

```
location ~ ^/document_download/(.*) {
  internal;
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;
  proxy_pass       $1;
}
```

My backend returns this (python):

```
headers = {
    "X-Accel-Redirect": f"/document_download/{url}",
}
```

The URL is dymanically generated and put in the return path.
NGINX converts this return path to the right URL and uses proxy_pass to give the PDF back to the user.

**API Gateway**

How can I solve this in API Gateway? Should I use HTTP endpoint and Integration response mapping for this?